# Adding dynamic Attributes to JPA entities

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, dynamic

I'm building a web app with a common base of entities for all customer

Now some customers needs additional fields, but I don't want to add all. I thought about something like that:

```
@Embeddable
public class AdditionalDetails {

private String label;

private String text;

public AdditionalDetails() {}


    // autogenerated getters and setters, hashCode(), equals()
} 
    
@Entity
public class BusinessObject {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "string_id")
    private long id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKey(name = "language")
    @CollectionTable(schema = "label", name = "multilingual_string_map", 
              joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "string_id"))
    private Map<String, AdditionalDetails> map = new HashMap<String, AdditionalDetails>();

    public BusinessObject() {}

    // autogenerated getters and setters, hashCode(), equals()
}
```

No the problem is who I would I configure which properties are added to by BusinessObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `@Entity` annotation from the base class.
Then create subclasses from your base class and add the `@Entity` annotation to the subclasses.
Now you can avoid placing all attributes in the base class, instead you can add them to an appropriate subclass.

Comment: that's a good idea. But i wanted a generic solution where I put a config parameter or something similar to build the map

Comment: What you propose is not possible with JPA. This is because fields and methods must map to a database resource. What you are seeking is one field or accessor that when given some parameter, dynamically determines its mapping. This is not how JPA was architected.

Comment: All in all, my proposed answer is likely the best you can do to approximate the behavior you want. Please consider accepting it if it helps. Thanks a lot and good luck!